# Broadcasting video and bandwidth issue

Tags: video, broadcasting

I need to broadcast on the Internet weekly **live** video events.
One attempt was made with Skype and it worked pretty well, but it was only with one user. We expect 50 users and we have a low bandwidth here so I guess Skype won't be a solution.

What do you recommend for broadcasting live video events to 50 people with low bandwidth from the video source ? Free solutions are preferable.

Thanks!

Comment: [Broadcast and Media Technologies](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36807/broadcast-and-media-technologies) aims to capture more architectural and theoretical views around subjects like this. Join and invite others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have at least 300-500kps of upload bandwith available you can push an rtmp stream of your live event to a CDN like youtube, dailymotion, livestream ...

In terms of software I already used:

- Livestream, which provides among other things a tool called procaster with which you can broadcast your desktop, or a section of your desktop. You can even broadcast a capture of your skype window ! ( it will not be very beautiful, but it works ). Livestream also has many tools which allow to make a chat during your live event with the viewers of the event.
- Flash Media Encoder (aka FME ), which is a free tool provided by Adobe, which will encode to rtmp any video camera connected to your computer. You can then push it to a CDN like YouTube or DailyMotion.

All of this is free of charge, with sometimes some limits on the number of simultaneous viewer, and/on an ad-supporting scheme which will play an advertisement before your live video.

Comment: We are inviting experts to [Broadcast and Media Technologies](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36807/broadcast-and-media-technologies) which aims to capture more architectural and theoretical views around subjects like this. Join and invite others.

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be a Google+ hangout.  Especially if you want some sort of user interaction with-in the program.